# TypeError: $(...).val(...).html is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting json array from Ajax response, i am trying to add this in drop-down but I am getting error above error.
JSON array after stringyfy contain below array.

> [{"ID":"1","NAME":"Nevpro"},{"ID":"9","NAME":"Tushar"}]

```
<html>
<select name id='sel'>
</select>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(
function() {
    $('.filter-dropdown').change(function() {
        var lan = this.value;
        //alert(lan);
        //alert(lan)

        $.ajax({
                url: "http://10.10.1.84/services/request.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {lan : lan},
                success: function(data){
                    var data1=JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert(data1);

                    $.each(data1,function (key,value) {
                        alert(key);

                        $("#sel").append($('<option></option>').val(value.ID).html(value.NAME));

                     });
                }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like `$` is not referering to jQuery at that poing

Comment: You cannot chain `val` and `html`. Read the jquery docs.

Comment: you can try it like $('<option>').val(value.ID).text(value.NAME).appendTo('#sel')

Comment: it should be .text() instead of .html()

Answer (score 1):

You can define the [value and text as an object.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```
$("#sel").append(
  $('<option></option>',{
    value : value.ID,
    text : value.NAME
  })
);
```

---

**UPDATE :** Although there is one more bug, you are iterating over the stringified data so replace it with the object(which is the actual issue lies in your code).

```
$.each(data,.....
//-----^^^^------
```

Comment: error is not appearing but value is not appending to drop-down its only a large blank box.

Comment: when I alert the key its gives value up to 0 to 54,but its need to give only two key 0 and 1

Comment: and when i alert value it alert like {,  ", I, D, " ,:,,", ,1,", ....and so on...each word separately alerting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data1,function (key,value) {
    alert(key);
    $('#sel').append('<option value='+value.ID+'>'+value.NAME+'</option>');
});
```

You need not add $ inside append again. You can add options like this inside your loop.

Comment: thanks for answer but not working i get 54 drop-downs with same name as undefined

Comment: when I alert the key its gives value up to 0 to 54,but its need to give only two key 0 and 1

Comment: then your data1 is wrong. If you fix it and confirm that it has keys named ID and NAME then this code should work.

Comment: When i did not do stringify then data alert show [object object] ,but alert of value get correct like 1 and Nevpro etc...then what is problem please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think this shoud solve your problem

```js
var optionTemp = document.createElement('option')
for (i in data1) {
   var option = optionTemp.cloneNode();
   option.value = data1[i][ID];
   option.text = data1[i][NAME];
   $('#sel').append(option);
}
```